# See what changes will be done to the DB before saving an import in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, import

I have an import/export from/to xls of my Products, SubProducts & Costs of my DB. The thing is an importation can make big changes on the DB. That's why I need to add one step: the preview of the changes and a confirm link.

I have no idea how I could "simulate" the import, log the differences, NOT save changes yet and wait for the user's confirmation.

Can somebody help me on this?

(Rails 2.3.11, PostGreSQL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should leverage the dirty attributes:

Simulate your importation and set your object with the new values:

```
obj.foo
#=> "old_foo"
obj.foo = "new_foo"
# Don't save!
obj.changes
#=> { 'foo' => ["old_foo", "new_foo"] }
```

To get the changes stored somewhere in memory, consider:

- using cache
- adding a row in you table where you'd serialize everything

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I don't really understand your last phrase:
"adding a row in your table where you'd serialize everything"
Can you develop your advice?
Thanks again